# Android Studio - How do I get the widget to open the URL instead of the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to get the widget to open the form directly. Currently, the widget has to be selected from the home screen, then the button in the app needs to be selected to redirect to the form.

How can I get the Widget on the home screen to redirect straight to the form?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.redirectwidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import app.com.sample.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button UrlOpen;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UrlOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        UrlOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Getintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://form.jotform.com/212974804322152"));
                startActivity(Getintent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AppWidget.java**

```
package com.example.redirectwidget;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import app.com.sample.R;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetID : appWidgetIds){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_register, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetID, views);

        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.redirectwidget.MainActivity" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Click Here" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**app_widget_info.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.RedirectWidget.AppWidget.Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.RedirectWidget.AppWidgetContainer">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Register" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe deep linking will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent in the OnCreate method in MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.codinginflow.widgetexample.R;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button UrlOpen;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent Getintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(Getintent);
            }
    }
```